# How to write loop that ends in negative number (MyProgrammingLab 11138)

Tags: c++

Consider this data sequence: "3 11 5 5 5 2 4 6 6 7 3 -8". Any value  that is the same as the immediately preceding value  is considered a CONSECUTIVE DUPLICATE. In this example, there are three such consecutive duplicates: the 2nd and 3rd 5s and the second 6. Note that the last 3 is not a consecutive duplicate because it was preceded by a 7.
Write some code that uses a loop to read such a sequence of non-negative integers , terminated by a negative number. When the code exits the loop it should print the number of consecutive duplicates encountered. In the above case, that value  would be 3.

This is a question from MyProgrammingLab exercise 11138.  This needs to be written in C++, and we are not allowed to use any arrays yet.  Thank you so much for your help.  I really appreciate it.

Here is what I have so far:

```
int firstNumber;
int secondNumber;
int duplicates;

secondNumber = duplicates = 0;
cin >> firstNumber;

while (firstNumber > -1 && secondNumber > -1)
{
    secondNumber 
    if (firstNumber == secondNumber)
    {
        duplicates++
    }
    firstNumber = secondNumber;
}

cout << duplicates;
```

Comment: `secondNumber` isn't a valid statement.

Comment: Apart from the syntax errors, what happens when you compile and run it?  Note that your `cin >> firstNumber` is outside of the while loop so you never request more input.

Comment: Write out a flowchart/diagram/list of steps to take to plan it out before starting to write code. It's helped me in figuring out algorithms before. You're on the right track with this one, just fill in the missing steps.

Comment: `std::distance(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end())`... ([Demo](https://ideone.com/YKwDFy).)

Comment: @KerrekSB: You forgot "consecutive"

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf No, he's right. [std::unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) _"Eliminates all but the first element from every **consecutive** group of equivalent elements..."_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Just a little change is needed.

```
cin >> firstNumber;
while ( firstNumber > -1 ) { // only firstNumber alone can handle this.
    cin >> secondNumber;
    if (firstNumber == secondNumber)
        duplicates++;
    else
        firstNumber = secondNumber;
}
```

**EDIT -** As suggested by  Bob__ a single one `cin` can also solve this.

```
int firstNumber,secondNumber = -1, duplicates = 0;
do {
    cin >> firstNumber;
    if ( secondNumber == -1) {
        secondNumber = firstNumber;
    }else {
        if ( secondNumber == firstNumber ) 
            duplicates++;
        else
            secondNumber = firstNumber;
    }
} while(firstNumber > 0 );
```

Comment: Try using only one `cin` (to read `firstNumber`) in the while condition and then `secondNumber = firstNumber;` to update...

Comment: Thanks you so much everyone.  I was stuck on that one forever.  Have a nice day!

Comment: understood..@Bob__